# Failing wheel while installing pyshipping via pip

Tags: python, python-wheel

I am trying to install the package "pyShipping" and "pyShipping-python3" to solve a bin packing problem.

Trying to do `pip install wheel` returns `Requirement already satisfied: wheel in e:\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (0.31.1)`, so I assume it is working

However, trying `pip install pyshipping` gives the following log:

```
Collecting pyshipping
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/89/a1b8ae8a7c69c56a4f0aad97d73fa929514ab2734014c0ae5e65978f5708/pyShipping-1.7.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: cython in e:\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from pyshipping) (0.28.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyshipping
  Building wheel for pyshipping (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'e:\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\M2407\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yf7s_nan\\pyshipping\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\M2407\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-y2xhk3du' --python-tag cp36:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
  copying pyshipping\addressvalidation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
  copying pyshipping\binpack.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
  copying pyshipping\binpack_simple.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
  copying pyshipping\package.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
  copying pyshipping\shipment.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
  copying pyshipping\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers
  copying pyshipping\carriers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\fortras
  copying pyshipping\fortras\bordero.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\fortras
  copying pyshipping\fortras\entl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\fortras
  copying pyshipping\fortras\fortras_stat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\fortras
  copying pyshipping\fortras\test.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\fortras
  copying pyshipping\fortras\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\fortras
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd
  copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoute.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd
  copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoute_test.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd
  copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd
  running egg_info
  writing pyShipping.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to pyShipping.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to pyShipping.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to pyShipping.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'pyShipping.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'pyShipping.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying pyshipping\3dbpp.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
  copying pyshipping\binpack_3dbpp.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
  copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\COUNTRY -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
  copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\DEPOTS.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
  copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\LOCATION.DE -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
  copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\LOCATION.EN -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
  copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\LOCATION.FR -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
  copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\ROUTES.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
  copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\SERVICE -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
  copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\SERVICEINFO.CS -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
  copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\SERVICEINFO.DE -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
  copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\SERVICEINFO.EE -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
  copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\SERVICEINFO.EN -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
  running build_ext
  building 'pyshipping.binpack_3dbpp' extension
  error: Don't know how to compile pyshipping/binpack_3dbpp.pyx
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyshipping
  Running setup.py clean for pyshipping
Failed to build pyshipping
Installing collected packages: pyshipping
  Running setup.py install for pyshipping ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'e:\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\M2407\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yf7s_nan\\pyshipping\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\M2407\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nkivjlx2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
    copying pyshipping\addressvalidation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
    copying pyshipping\binpack.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
    copying pyshipping\binpack_simple.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
    copying pyshipping\package.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
    copying pyshipping\shipment.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
    copying pyshipping\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers
    copying pyshipping\carriers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\fortras
    copying pyshipping\fortras\bordero.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\fortras
    copying pyshipping\fortras\entl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\fortras
    copying pyshipping\fortras\fortras_stat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\fortras
    copying pyshipping\fortras\test.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\fortras
    copying pyshipping\fortras\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\fortras
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd
    copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoute.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd
    copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoute_test.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd
    copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd
    running egg_info
    writing pyShipping.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pyShipping.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to pyShipping.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to pyShipping.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'pyShipping.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'pyShipping.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying pyshipping\3dbpp.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
    copying pyshipping\binpack_3dbpp.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
    copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\COUNTRY -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
    copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\DEPOTS.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
    copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\LOCATION.DE -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
    copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\LOCATION.EN -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
    copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\LOCATION.FR -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
    copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\ROUTES.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
    copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\SERVICE -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
    copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\SERVICEINFO.CS -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
    copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\SERVICEINFO.DE -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
    copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\SERVICEINFO.EE -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
    copying pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables\SERVICEINFO.EN -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyshipping\carriers\dpd\georoutetables
    running build_ext
    building 'pyshipping.binpack_3dbpp' extension
    error: Don't know how to compile pyshipping/binpack_3dbpp.pyx
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'e:\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\M2407\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yf7s_nan\\pyshipping\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\M2407\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nkivjlx2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\M2407\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yf7s_nan\pyshipping\
```

Is there any other thing that I need to install other than python 3.7? I also trying to install C develoment package, but I may have done something wrong.

Comment: Sometimes I've gotten errors like these when you need to be sudo.

Comment: You made a good point. I am using windows, however even running the command in Administrator, it fails. Same log